# Get APK package name

Tags: javascript, android, html, apk

Can I get APK package name from uploaded file in JS?

I'm using HTML5 to upload the file and I would like to get the package name of the selected file.

```
<input type="file"/>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Are you by any chance running Node.js as a webserver? I don't think it is possible to do this client side.

Comment: I reckon it's *possible*... use the HTML5 file input APIs to get the APK as a blob, pass it to an unzipping library to extract `AndroidManifest.xml`, and parse that XML to get the package name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I used the amazing [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) library to get the AndroidManifest.xml content and convert its content to searchable string using the following code:

```
function getPackageName(apkBlobAsByteArray) {
            // Unzipping zip blob
            var zip = new JSZip(apkBlobAsByteArray);

            // Getting AndroidManifest.xml and decompress it
            var androidCompress = zip.files['AndroidManifest.xml'];
            var androidNonCompress = androidCompress._data.getContent();

            // Reading to content to a searchable string
            var packageNameArray = [];
            var textArray = String(androidNonCompress).split(',');
            for (var i = 0, len = textArray.length; i < len; i++) {
                if (textArray[i] !== 0) {
                    packageNameArray.push(textArray[i]);
                }
            }

            // Searching for package name
            var startPattern = 'manifest';
            var androidText = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, packageNameArray).toString().toLowerCase();
            var packageName = androidText.substring(androidText.indexOf(startPattern) +
                startPattern.length, androidText.indexOf('uses'));
            // Remove version from package name
            packageName = packageName.substring(0, packageName.indexOf(packageName.match(/\d+/)[0]));

            return packageName;
        }
```

Comment: jszip is updated now and this code dosent work anymore , you should refactor it.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you can use app-info-parser from https://github.com/chenquincy/app-info-parser.

In your browser you can use JS Deliver to include a script tag pointing to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/chenquincy/app-info-parser/dist/app-info-parser.min.js.

The code may be like:

```
var parser = new AppInfoParser(files[0])
parser.parse().then(function (result) {
  console.log('app info ----> ', result);
  console.log('icon base64 ----> ', result.icon);
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log('err ----> ', err);
});
```